# WebView with small scroll bars - how?

Tags: cocoa

I'm putting a WebView in an NSPanel and would like it to use small scroll bars.
How do I tell it to? (Can't be done in Interface Builder)

I realize a WebView has a number of different types of subviews, depending on the content that's loaded. But suppose I'm loading a web page with no frames. What view would contain the main vertical scroll bar? Is there an NSScrollView somewhere or is this managed differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a document has loaded into a frame you can access the `NSView` for the document and then access its enclosing scroll view, allowing you to set the scrollers to the size you want:

```
- (void)loadWebView
{
    webView.frameLoadDelegate = self;
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://daringfireball.net"]]];
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    //get the scroll view that contains the frame contents
    NSScrollView* scrollView = [[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] enclosingScrollView];
    [[scrollView verticalScroller] setControlSize: NSSmallControlSize];
    [[scrollView horizontalScroller] setControlSize: NSSmallControlSize];
}
```